# PHP Order By not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my PHP Query, but it doesn't seem to order the results. Everything else works fine.

```
SELECT *  
FROM   `main` 
WHERE  `user_legacy` LIKE '%".$name."%' 
ORDER BY 'user_legacy' DESC LIMIT ".$limit
```

Comment: try removing the quotes in `ORDER BY 'user_legacy'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use backticks (') to quote column names in SQL, not the normal single quote (').

```
ORDER BY `user_legacy` DESC
```

Also, if you don't do any kind of vetting or your input, that query is potentially vulnerable to an SQL injection.

Comment: I do strip the inputs, so there is no sql injection possibility. thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't quote the column name.

```
ORDER BY user_legacy
```

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY` needs a column name, you're passing it a string. Lose the quotes.